# Two separate database queries to relate separate tables with Drupal 7 module?

Tags: sql, database, drupal, standards

I am developing a custom module for a site I'm working on and have created the following code. This is my first module, so any ideas of what I could be doing better would be appreciate.

As it is, this module works perfectly for me. But, I want to optimize it and be sure that I fix shoddy code.

Thanks!

The function in question is as follows:

```
// Declared variables for future incrementation
$total=0;
$countOne=0;
$countTwo=0;
$countThree=0;
$countOld=0;

// Call the native global user object from Drupal
global $user;
$userID = $user->uid;       

// Check for nodes of given type owned by current user
$sql = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'content_type' AND uid = " . $userID);     

// Iteratively checks each node id against a custom Drupal field on a separate table
foreach ($sql as $record) {         

// SQL query for all custom fields attached to the node id given above
$query = db_query("SELECT * FROM {field_birth} WHERE entity_id = " . $record->nid);         
$result = $query->fetchObject();                

// The unmodified birth format (Y-m-d 00:00:00)
$originalBirth = $result->field_date_of_birth_value;

// The sanitized birth format for comparison (Y-m-d)
$birth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($originalBirth));

// The current date/time (Y-m-d)
$now = date('Y-m-d');

//Future dates (Y-m-d)
$one_year = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($birth)));
$two_years = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 years', strtotime($birth)));
$three_years = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 years', strtotime($birth)));         

// A count of all records returned before logical statements
$total++;

// Logic to determine the age of the records
if($now < $one_year) {
    $countOne++;
}               
else if($now >= $one_year && $now < $two_years) {
    $countTwo++;
}
else if($now >= $two_years && $now < $three_years) {
    $countThree++;
}
else {
    $countOld++;
}
```

My question is, can I avoid having two separate database queries to hit both tables? I am not really sure how to go about that. Also, am I doing things in a manner which will be resource intensive and highly inefficient? As I am not a programmer by trade, I am not certain when code is 'good'. I do want to try my best to make this good code though since it is a module for a website I hope will last a long time.

Thank you stackoverflow community!

EDIT: The code I got working thanks to Mike is as follows. If anyone has a similar question / problem hopefully this will help!

```
// Join field_birth_table to nodes of given type owned by current user      
$sql = db_select('node', 'n');      
$sql->join('field_birth_table', 'b', 'n.nid = b.entity_id');
$sql

    ->fields('b', array('field_birth_field_value', 'entity_id'))
    ->condition('n.type', 'content_type')
    ->condition('n.status', '1')
    ->condition('n.uid', $user->uid)
    ->addTag('node_access');

    $results = $sql->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join between the `node` and `field_birth` table:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');

$query->leftJoin('field_birth', 'b', '(b.entity_id = n.nid AND b.entity_type = :node)', array(':node' => 'node'));
$query
    ->fields('b', array())
    ->condition('n.type', 'content_type')
    ->condition('n.uid', $user->uid)

$results = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, that was very helpful and it worked like a charm! One question though. Logically it makes sense to me that a join will have way less performance impact than an sql query nested inside a foreach() loop, but I am reading mixed things about it. Join is the way to go, right? Thanks again, I'd vote you up by don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Well it depends, a join can be slower in some cases (when working on large data and not foreign keys are defined). But in this case, you only execute 1 query instead of 1 + (x * the result of first query). Imagine if you have 100 results, it would execute 101 sql queries. You can accept the answer, if you aren't allowed to upvote ;)